# Carrying contraceptives in Abu Dhabi

Tags: local-customs, uae, abu-dhabi

Can me and my girlfriend (not married) carry on our hand luggages some condoms and a morning after pill in Abu Dhabi or we could face some troubles with local authorities?

I heard that in this emirate they are more authoritarian than Dubai.

Comment: A quick google search suggests contraceptives are freely and readily available in all of UAE, and not forbidden to bring into the country (for personal use)